# Does voyage souvent make sense?

Tags: traduction, phrase

I am trying to figure out how to say travel often in French. I ran “travel often” through Google translator and got “voyage souvent”.

But I have two questions

- Is the translation correct
- Does that phrase even make sense in French?

Comment: Tapez votre phrase sur https://www.deepl.com/translator et cliquez ensuite sur "souvent" vous aurez des synonymes

Comment: Yes this make sense you can say "Je voyage souvent"

Answer (score 2):

Usually, phrases without context are difficult to deal with because there is very rarely a full one-for-one relationship between English and French vocabulary but in that specific case, I see no way for *voyage souvent* not to rightly translate "travel often", outside conjugation issues, e.g.:

> Do you travel often ?
>
> *Tu voyages souvent ?* / *Vous voyagez souvent ?*

Answer (score 0):

You may ask to some friend : "Est-ce que tu voyages souvent à l'étranger ?"  He will probably answer : "Non, seulement de temps en temps". Or : "Oui, je dois le faire pour mon travail !"